# Run a PKG file from the same folder as an Applescript

Tags: shell, scripting, applescript, automator

I have an apple script that is supposed to install a printer driver with admin priviliges, followed by a bash script that adds the printer based on the ip address to a computer. The apple script and pkg file are located in the same folder.

I'm kinda stuck on on how to write the apple script so that the pkg can run relative to were its located. My goal is to host the script somewhere and other macs can run and install the same printer. Any ideas guys?

This is what I have so far

on run {input, parameters}

```
do shell script "sudo  installer -allowUntrusted -pkg  Driver.pkg -target /"
with administrator privileges

return input
```

end run

I get an error saying the path Driver.pkg is invalid.  The script and the pkg are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With or without administrator privileges, the working directory of `do shell script` is always `/` (the root folder of the startup drive).

But, you could do this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myFolder to (quoted form of (POSIX path of (parent of (path to me) as string)))
end tell

do shell script ¬
  "installer -allowUntrusted -pkg " & myFolder & "Driver.pkg -target /" ¬
  with administrator privileges
```

The `sudo` is redundant if you are using `with administrator privileges`.